# How to parse json which is having array in array

Tags: jquery

I am reciving JSON data in this format .

```
[
    {
        "id": "0004",
        "name": "Thums Up",
        "image": {
            "url": "pepsicup.jpg",
            "width": 200,
            "height": 200
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "category_name": "can",
                "image": "images/0001.jpg",
                "type": [
                    {
                        "type": "250ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "300ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "330ml"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "category_name": "bottle",
                "image": "images/0001.jpg",
                "type": [
                    {
                        "type": "350ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "600ml"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "category_name": "fountain",
                "image": "images/0001.jpg",
                "type": [
                    {
                        "type": "small"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "large"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0005",
        "name": "Pepsi",
        "image": {
            "url": "images/0001.jpg",
            "width": 200,
            "height": 200
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "category_name": "can",
                "image": "images/0001.jpg",
                "type": [
                    {
                        "type": "250ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "300ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "330ml"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "category_name": "bottle",
                "image": "images/0001.jpg",
                "type": [
                    {
                        "type": "350ml"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "600ml"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "category_name": "fountain",
                "image": "images/0001.jpg",
                "type": [
                    {
                        "type": "small"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "large"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If once the name is matched to  Thums Up , is it possible to retrieve the **category_name**

**can , bottle and fountain** in my case ??

I have tried below , but could't able to continue once the name is matched ??

Could you please help me retriving the category_name for **Thumps Up** .

```
var result = JSON.stringify(retdata);



for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
        {
            if(i.name="Thums Up")
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: You want `JSON.parse` not `JSON.stringify`. `.parse` will turn you JSON (string) into a javascript object.

Comment: FWIW, `i.name` doesn't make sense, since `i` is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have array and then in array item there is another array, you need to do like this:

```
$.each(retdata,function(index,item){

$.each(item,function(index1,item1){

    console.log(item1);
});
    console.log(item);

});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/J6sSm/)

Comment: so again do i need to use $.each on item1 to get the cateory names of ThumpsuP ??

Comment: @user3674364: `category` contains an array. You have to iterate over it explicitly or use something like http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/, depending on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: yes @FelixKling is right in Category there is another array

Comment: so you will have to write another each or use map inside second each